# Python: Update plist file's values

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, plist

Script that can automate updating specific fields in `plist` file. I want to update specific value in `plist`.

I want to change "Color" value. how is possible in python 3.5?

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"   
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>AlarmFilter</key>
<true/>
 <key>AlarmsDisabled</key>
<false/>
<key>AttachmentFilter</key>
<true/>
<key>AutoRefresh</key>
<true/>
<key>Checked</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>Color</key>
<string>#808000FF</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

i wrote this code:

```
import plistlib
answer = plistlib.readPlist('plist_path')

ans = dict.values(answer)
ans1 = dict.keys(answer)


que = input('Enter Element Name:- \n')
try:
p  = answer[que] = "ravi"
plistlib.writePlist(p, answer)
except:
print("Failure")
```

Comment: You must show us your effort to solve your issue. Otherwise some might think you want them to work for you, for free. Great manager.

Comment: Thanks Ravi! Do you get any error?

Comment: @J.Chomel i want to replace string in the plist, when user enter specific string it's automatically change in plist.

no, i did not get any error but also not replace specific string.